# what is the mean of + in front of a line in php

Tags: php, diff

I have a question about syntax in php. What is the mean of + in following line? Thanks!

```
+$array['key1']['key2'] = "value"
```

Comment: Is this from a diff?

Comment: Ed Heal might be right. Never saw this syntax before.

Comment: might seen Objective C syntax :)

Comment: Can you post more lines from the same file to see its context (to verify if it's a diff or not, or a typo).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It means that someone pressed `enter` in previous line

Comment: If this appears literally in the code, it is superfluous and has no effect but [it is not invalid](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RqvWkm). I'm a little surprised it is still valid since it has no effect, but there you go. On the other hand, leading the line with a `-` does [have the effect](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NJgoNl) of inverting the sign on a number.

Comment: @Alp - Your link to your web site on your profile does not work.

Comment: I work with github, and a colleague maybe coped some code directly from github, but curiously is that apache and php doesn't notify any problem with these lines. I think that a line with this kind of declaration have a meaning but i don't understand what is the meaning. Maybe "+" is sum operator on a empty variable and does change nothing and then the allocation is made. so correct code. Make sense?

Comment: @Ed Heal - thanks, the page is not completed yet. I exchanged it with a link to [my open source project](https://github.com/alp82/abmash)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no meaning, it is superfluous. You can write the exact same statement without the plus:

```
$array['key1']['key2'] = "value"
```

If you have that from a [unified `diff` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format), it means that this line was *added*. So that plus is not PHP code, it is a marker for that line in the diff/patch. The other marker is minus `-` for removing a line.

Comment: Oh, the satisfaction of giving you the upvote that ticks your displayed rep over to 50K :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is used for showing the line diff. in different versions of a same file.

Deleted line can be shown as,

```
- $array['key1']['key2'] = "value";
```

Added line can be shown as,

```
+ $array['key1']['key2'] = "value";
```

Answer (score -3):

**Edit: Apparently I misunderstood the question, so this answer is invalid.**

It look like a "shorthand" technique.

```
+$array['key1']['key2'] = "value"
```

should be the same as:

```
$array['key1']['key2'] = $array['key1']['key2'] + "value"
```

I have never seen it used like this, so I could be wrong. I know it as:

```
$x++;
```

is the same as:
`$x += 1;` or `$x = $x + 1;`
and I know that `++$x;` exist also as a pre-increment

Comment: No, no, no shorthand technique: http://codepad.org/SzADy6Bi not same as `+=` no, no *sing* ;)